# Slicing a DataFrame by conditions where parametres != None?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose with have this dataframe with three columns 'ABC' containing random numbers. The user gets to choose the threshold conditions by which he wants to slice this dataframe. If one the conditions is 'None' it means there is no limit condition. How can I skip slicing by the condition where the threshold is None ?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

condition_A = [75,66,None]
condition_B = [50,14,30]
condition_C = [66,None,37]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

output_dfs = []
for cd1,cd2,cd3 in zip(condition_A, condition_B, condition_C):
  x = df.copy()
  x = x[(x['A'] < cd1) & (x['B'] < cd2) & (x['C'] < cd3)]  
  output_dfs.append(x)
  print(x)
```

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output?

Comment: The question is so dumb I thought it doesn't require an output. For example, If Condition_A is 'None' it should just skip slicing this column 'A' & leave all of its values then move to the columns 'B' & 'C'

Comment: If you still think the output is  necessary to the comprehension I can add it

Comment: Do you mind to check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider adding an extra step where you replace `None` with `np.inf`

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100, size=(100, 3)),
    columns=list('ABC'))
```

## Condition

```py
Condition_A = [75, 66, None]
cd_A = [x if x is not None else np.inf 
        for x in condition_A]
```

## Filter

This takes only the rows where all conditions are satisfied

```py
df[df.lt(cd_A).all(1)]
```

Comment: It is identical to the solution I avoided, which is replacing 'None' with the maximum value of the associated column. However, you did it in a clean way so I'm just gonna go with this. Thanks mate

Comment: @KeyserSoze keep in mind that this way of filtering it is very flexible. In particular when you have many conditions as you avoid to write all of them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check each value for `None` before you employ it.  Instead of

```
(x['A'] < cd1)
```

use

```
(cd1 == None | x['A'] < cd1)
```

Comment: It's the logical or operator.

Comment: I get the following error, TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [int64] array and scalar of type [NoneType]

Comment: You have just demonstrated the problem of an incomplete post :-).    Please replace the `None` check with one that is valid for the data type you're using.  You should know how to do that already; perhaps `is`, or something you look up.  i.e. the repair is left as an exercise for the student.